# Annotate a POJO as Component

Tags: java, spring, components

May I annotate a simple pojo by @Component ?

It is because IntelliJ says :

> could not autowire, no beans found

Thanks

Comment: IntelliJ says that where you can use annotation!

Comment: Why do you need to set pojo as component ?

Comment: What should be the annotation in pojo so ? Because intellij indicates that Incant do @autowire for the pojo ...

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can annotate pojo with @Component, and then you can autowire it within another pojo also annotated with @Component e.g:

```
@Component
public class Computer {

    @Autowired
    Procesor procesor;

    public void printName() {
        System.out.println("486DX");
    }
}

@Component
public class Procesor {
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringOneApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SpringOneApplication.class, args);
        Computer computer = (Computer) context.getBean("computer");
        computer.printName();
    }
}
```